# Changing Background Colour with a While Loop

Tags: javascript

I wrote a snippet of code so a prompt would come up in chrome asking for a colour and using a loop it would keep asking and keep changing the colour till an empty string is given. If the loop is taken out it changes the colour but with the loop added in the background, the colour does not change. Is there a logical error I am missing?

```
let empty=false;
while(empty===false){
  const colour= prompt("Give me a colour");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor=colour;
  if(colour===""){
    empty=true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript blocks repaints of the document.

Until the JS finishes (which it never does until `colour` is `""`), the browser won't have an opportunity to update the display to reflect the changes you made to the DOM.

You can't use a `while` loop for this. Use `setTimeout` recursively instead.

```js
function update_background() {
    const colour = prompt("Give me a colour");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor=colour;
    if (colour) {
        setTimeout(update_background);
    }
}

update_background();
```